# Unable to delete folders or files in SharePoint site linked to a Team

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, team-sites, delete, settings

I am unable to delete folders or documents in a SharePoint library that is linked to a particular MS Team. When I click on the ellipses of a folder or file the delete option is not there (it is there for other SharePoint/teams libraries).

I have checked to see if there are any files checked out and there are none.

I have managed to delete the folder by going into Classic SharePoint view and the deleting via the files tab. But I am just confused as to why I couldn't delete them in the normal way. I have checked the settings for the site and can't see anything out of the ordinary.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that these folders are connected to channels that exist in Microsoft Teams. For each standard channel that exists in the Microsoft Team, there is a folder in the SharePoint site. In order to delete the folders, you would need to first delete the channel and then delete the folder afterwards. More information can be found here:

[How SharePoint Online and OneDrive for Business interact with Microsoft Teams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/sharepoint-onedrive-interact)

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I successfully deleted the folder or file in the modern document library linked to Teams.

I want to confirm some information with you:

1.Do other users occur the same issue?

2.If you open the site in different browser, whether the **Delete** option is still missing in modern experience, try to clear browser cache then compare the result.

3.Does this behavior happen on other site connect to another teams? Please change site to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with this as well.

Currently, we want to archive the files associated with a channel and remove the channel, so I tested it and it worked fine. But when I went to delete the test folders it won't let me do it. It thinks it still associated with the test channel, but it has already been deleted. How can I remove these folders?

Thanks.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/117516)